# Select query with join

Tags: oracle, select, join

I have tables:

[image: diagram of tables]

How can I select NEWS with concrete TAGS, for example with two TAGS?

It's my wrong variant:

```
SELECT DISTINCT news.news_id, news.CREATION_DATE, news.MODIFICATION_DATE, news.FULL_TEXT, news.TITLE, news.SHORT_TEXT
    FROM
      news
      INNER JOIN
      news_tags
        ON news.news_id = news_tags.news_id
        WHERE news_tags.TAG_ID = 1 AND news_tags.TAG_ID = 3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get news with tags 1 and 3 you should check that a record with tag_id 1 and a record with tag_id 3 exists in the news_tags table. Right now you're asking for news whose tag is 1 and at the same time 3, which doesn't really make sense.

Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT news.news_id, news.CREATION_DATE, news.MODIFICATION_DATE, news.FULL_TEXT, news.TITLE, news.SHORT_TEXT
FROM news INNER JOIN news_tags ON news.news_id = news_tags.news_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM news_tags
              WHERE news_id = news.news_id
              AND tag_id = 1)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM news_tags
            WHERE news_id = news.news_id
            AND tag_id = 3);
```

Comment: Sorry but each NEWS can have multiple tags. Your query gives me NEWS which have tag 1 or tag 3. I need to get news with tags 1 and 3

Comment: Sorry @Pavel, I didn't understand what you were trying to get. I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT news.news_id, news.CREATION_DATE, news.MODIFICATION_DATE, news.FULL_TEXT, news.TITLE, news.SHORT_TEXT
FROM
  news
  INNER JOIN
  news_tags
    ON news.news_id = news_tags.news_id
       inner join Tags on Tags.Tag_Id = news_tags.Tag_Id
    WHERE news_tags.TAG_ID = 1 AND news_tags.TAG_ID = 3;
```

Comment: This query gives me empty table as my query.